# getLocation() to database as an AJAX POST request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, postgresql, post

Users are being created on page load - by IP, (like Yik Yak). I'm getting GPS information from my users via getLocation(). Of course users are being created before I can get the GPS info to store, and thus lat and lng are null.

SO Instead of turning it into a cookie called by a method in rails and then saved, what I want to do is update user with an AJAX POST request and update the database.

Syntax-wise, how do I put in the request and how do I call it in the user_controller?

Thanks

Below is the code of me trying to do it in a cookie and it not working because I'm creating onload with IP (like Yik Yak).

application.html.erb

```
<body onload="getLocation()">
```

application. js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setGeoCookie);
        console.log("just got geolocation");
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        console.log("can't get geolocation");
    }
}

function setGeoCookie(position) {
  var cookie_val = position.coords.latitude + "|" + position.coords.longitude;
  document.cookie = "lat_lng=" + escape(cookie_val);
}
```

application_controller.rb

```
  def save_user_location
    if cookies[:lat_lng]
      @lat_lng = cookies[:lat_lng].split("|")
      @user=@current_user
      @user.latitude=@lat_lng[0]
      @user.longitude=@lat_lng[1]
      @user.save
      redirect_to users_index_path
    end
  end


  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    save_user_location
    @user = User.new
    set_current_ip


    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

schema.rb

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "current_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
  end
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Ok, i just did. thanks.